# Showing PHP output as it is being generated

Tags: php, jquery, flush

I've got a page that takes a few minutes to call some functions. I want the output to be displayed as it is generated. It can be simulated like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
    echo '*';
}
```

I've tried using flush() and ob_flush() but what happens is that it just displays all the asterisks at once after 5 seconds.

I tried something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').load('http://example.com/test.php');
});
```

But it just displays the asterisks all at once after 5 seconds.

Is there a type of header that I can put in the PHP file so that browsers load the content as they receive it?

Can jQuery AJAX allow the output to be displayed as it is being generated? If so, how?

Comment: have you called ob_start?

Comment: You can't do this reliably, since there are many buffers along the path from server script to client, but you should be splitting the task into a process and polling it anyway.

Comment: I've tried a few other people's code and some used ob_start

Comment: what's the point of this anyway? why do that on server side?

Comment: I made a utility that uses an online service to translate about 200 phrases into about 15 languages. It takes a few minutes to work and I wanted to display the language plus some dots to show the progress within that language (one dot per phrase). The translations are saved into a database. I thought doing it all in PHP would be faster than using some javascript/jQuery as well. Well at least it would be simpler to make.

Comment: On second thoughts maybe using jQuery I can do the translations in parallel rather than in series...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the examples from the jQuery.ajax() documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm not sure how to allow ajax to read an input that takes a few minutes to fully generate. BTW originally I used dots to show progress (it involved translating many phrases into other languages)

Comment: My first approach will be trying to split the big process into several small ones and call them one-by-one. But I don't know if it's possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the php functions flush and ob_flush

These should do what you want but remember to call ob_start()

Comment: I've tried using them as others have suggested in other topics but none of it works for me.

Comment: The following doesn't work:
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  ob_start();
  sleep(1);
  echo '*';
  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
 }

Comment: If I recall ob_start() has to be the very first function to be called on the script. Maybe that could be the reason why its not working.

Comment: I tried: 

ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
 ob_start();

 for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  sleep(1);
  echo '*';
  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
 }